# Sorting Map using Comparator by Map value

Tags: java, sorting, maps

lads
I'm not sure if I've seen any answer that suits my situation, despite on a  bunch of answers for situations which are look alike.
Anyway I'm a JAVA noob, so please be indulgent.

Here's the deal:
1. I have some class which is presents, let's say, a Person with name wich is a String.
2. Aslo I have a Comparator (MyComparator) that implements a Comparator interface for Persons.
The Comparator's constructor assumes that all comparable objects (Persons) will be kept in a Map.
In Comparator I have an int compare (Person p1, Person p2) method which is written by the following way:

```
   public int compare (Person personOne, Person personTwo) {
      if (personsMap.get(personOne)>personsMap.get(personTwo)) {
         return 1;
      } else if (personsMap.get(personOne)<personsMap.get(personTwo)) {
         return -1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
```

When I run something like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Person p1 = new Person ("Willy");
    Person p2 = new Person ("Billy");
    Person p3 = new Person ("Dilly");

    Map<Person, Integer> t = new HashMap<Person, Integer>();
    t.put(p1,12);
    t.put(p2,2);
    t.put(p3,100);

    List<Person> pl = new Arrays.asList(p1,p2,p3);
        Collections.sort(pl, new MyComparator(t));
}
```

I get NPE in MyComparator at the following row:

```
 if (personsMap.get(p1)>personsMap.get(p2))
```

Please, give me a clue, how to fix this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you've initialized the `personsMap` variable ? Can you show us the entire `MyComparator` class ?

Comment: Where and how do you assign personsMap?

Comment: The intent of the comparator is not to go anywhere to find the persons to compare. It receives them in its signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you are not initializing the map in your Comparator's constructor..

```
public MyComparator(Map<Person, Integer> t) {
        this.personsMap = t;
}
```

It's the most probable case in which you can have NPE. But you haven't inserted all the comparator class so it's just a guess ..

Comment: Hi all. Yep, that was a problem =) What I did, put hte following in the constructor: 'code' public MyComparator (Map <Person, Integer> t) { this.map= new HashMap <Person, Integer>(); } 'code' Shame on me =). Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Please show your `Comparator` class code. The following code works OK in your case.
But it is not clear why to use `map` instead of just a field in `Person`

```
public class Clazz {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Person p1 = new Person ("Willy");
        Person p2 = new Person ("Billy");
        Person p3 = new Person ("Dilly");

        Map<Person, Integer> t = new HashMap<Person, Integer>();
        t.put(p1,12);
        t.put(p2,2);
        t.put(p3,100);

        List<Person> pl = Arrays.asList(p1,p2,p3);
        Collections.sort(pl, new MyComparator(t));
        // [Person{name='Billy'}, Person{name='Willy'}, Person{name='Dilly'}]
        System.out.println(pl);
    }
}

class Person {
    private final String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            '}';
    }
}
class MyComparator implements Comparator<Person> {

    private Map<Person, Integer> t;

    public MyComparator(Map<Person, Integer> t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
        if (t.get(o1) < t.get(o2)) return -1;
        if (t.get(o1) == t.get(o2)) return 0;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me....

```
    public class Person {
    String name;

    public Person(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Person p1 = new Person ("Willy");
        Person p2 = new Person ("Billy");
        Person p3 = new Person ("Dilly");

        Map<Person, Integer> t = new HashMap<Person, Integer>();
        t.put(p1,12);
        t.put(p2,2);
        t.put(p3,100);

        List<Person> pl = Arrays.asList(p1, p2, p3);
        Collections.sort(pl, new MyComparator(t));
    }

}

class MyComparator implements  Comparator<Person>{
      private Map<Person, Integer> personsMap;

    public MyComparator(Map<Person, Integer> t) {
          this.personsMap = t;
    }

    public int compare (Person personOne, Person personTwo) {
          if (personsMap.get(personOne)>personsMap.get(personTwo)) {
             return 1;
          } else if (personsMap.get(personOne)<personsMap.get(personTwo)) {
             return -1;
          } else {
            return 0;
          }
}
}
```

Comment: But please let me say that a Comparator should only compare two Objects and have no notion of global state.
So passing a map with all elements to iterate is IMHO a bad design choice.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can use streams and lambda to do it in a functional way, without defining a proper Comparator. I did it with `String` as key, but you can of course use `Person`.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Willy", 12);
map.put("Billy", 2);
map.put("Dilly", 100);

List<String> list = map.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue))
                    .map(e -> e.getKey())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(list);
// ["Billy", "Willy", "Dilly"]
```